# Bulk import of a huge XML into an SQL Cellt

Tags: sql, xml, bcp, openrowset

I'm trying to import an XML file into a SQL cell to process it. My first idea is do an OPENROWSET to keep the XML and the just divide it with NODES. One of the XML its too huge to keep it on a CELL, so the OPENROWSET cut the XML, so It's impossible to work with it then. That is the code:

```html
    DECLARE  @XMLwithOpenXML TABLE
    (
        Id              INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        XMLData         XML,
        LoadedDateTime  DATETIME
    )

    INSERT INTO @XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
    SELECT      CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn
                ,GETDATE() 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\PP015.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS x;
    
    SELECT * FROM @XMLwithOpenXML
```

The second option is use the BCP to do the same, but I'm getting an error.

```html
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500) 

    SET @sql = 'bcp [ExternaDB].[dbo].[xmltab] IN "C:\temp\PP015.xml" -T -c'
    EXEC xp_cmdshell  @sql

    select * from xmltab
```

[image]

I want to know if I'm on the correct way (How to work with an XML when is already in an SQL cell I know how to do it) and how I can BULK import the full XML into a cell without Length constraint.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the XML file on the file system?

Please try the following solution. It is very similar to yours with three differences:

- `SINGLE_BLOB` instead of `SINGLE_CLOB`
- No need in `CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)`
- `DEFAULT` clause is used for the *LoadedDateTime* column

Additionally, you can use SSIS for the task. SSIS has a streaming XML Source Adapter with no XML file size limitation.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlData XML,
    LoadedDateTime DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);

INSERT INTO @tbl(XmlData)
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\temp\PP015.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It didn't work, it's still cutting the xml. The file size is 2.313.061 bytes. When the selected is execute, after trying to read the XML, SQL shows this message. 

Unable to show XML. The following error happened:
Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: LTAX1, ListaMateriales, n0:MT_OrdenProceso. Line 1, position 2097154.

One solution is to increase the number of characters retrieved from the server for XML data. To change this setting, on the Tools menu, click Options.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but I found the solution. SQL has configurate a maxium characters retrieved for XML data. To solve this issue just we have to reconfigure this parameter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agzPD.png)